# Error 1904 Module *.dll failed to register

Tags: windows-7

During installation of PegaReach s/w, I found the below mentioned error message

**"Error 1904. Module *.dll failed to register. HRESULT -2147024770. Contact your support personnel. (text)" in "Installer Information"**

*.dll->name of .dll files

Please suggest me suitable solutions to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Can you manually register the dll files yourself?

Comment: No, actually its 12 .dll files for single installation and I have to do that in 100 PCs, its quite problematic.

Comment: You can write a .bat script that does it when the user logs into their profile.  I was more interested in knowing the answer, if you were to manually register the file, if it would work or not.